# Autofac not resolving model binder dependencies

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, autofac

In my container I've registered my IModelBinder's and the Autofac model binder provider:

```
builder.RegisterWebApiModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.RegisterWebApiModelBinderProvider();
```

I'm binding my model binder to a class using the ModelBinder attribute on the class itself:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(RequestContextModelBinder))]
public class RequestContext
{
    // ... properties etc.
}
```

And the model binder itself, with a dependency:

```
public class RequestContextModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly ISomeDependency _someDependency;

    public RequestContextModelBinder(IAccountsRepository someDependency)
    {
        _someDependency = someDependency;
    }

    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // ... _someDependency is null
    }
}
```

From a controller, I can verify that Autofac correctly injects both the ISomeDependency and the model binder. However the dependency on the model binder is not injected.

When accessing an endpoint that has the RequestContext class as a parameter, I'm getting the "No parameterelss constructor"-exception, that relates to the model binder.

Any ideas?

---

## Update:

Thanks to nemesv, it turns out that it most likely doesn't make any sense to call `RegisterWebApiModelBinders` in Web API 2. An issue has been [reported](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=484&thanks=484&ts=1390140942) to Autofac.

To register model binders, one needs to call:

```
builder.RegisterType<RequestContextModelBinder>().AsModelBinderForTypes(typeof(RequestContext));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you explicitly specify a `Type` in the `ModelBinderAttribute` then Wep.Api tries to get an instance with the given type form the `DependencyResolver`.

However Autofac registers the model binder types with `IModelBinder` interface so when Wep.Api tries to resolve your binder with its concrete type the resolution fails and Wep.Api will fallback to `Activator.CreateInctance` to create the model binder instance which fails on your custom constructor.

You can fix this with registering your `RequestContextModelBinder` as self:

```
builder.RegisterType<RequestContextModelBinder>().AsSelf();
```

Or you can just remove the type from the `ModelBinderAttribute`:

```cs
[ModelBinder]
public class RequestContext
{
    // ... properties etc.
}
```

If there is no type given in the `ModelBinderAttribute` then Wep.API asks the current `ModelBinderProvider` for a binder for your model type which in this case the `AutofacWebApiModelBinderProvider` which will resolve your `RequestContextModelBinder` correctly.

However the `AutofacWebApiModelBinderProvider` only resolves your binder if you have correctly registered it with

```
builder.RegisterType<RequestContextModelBinder>()
       .AsModelBinderForTypes(typeof (RequestContext));
```

So writing `RegisterWebApiModelBinders` is not enough your need to use the `AsModelBinderForTypes` when registering your binders.

Comment: That makes sense. However I am still unable to make it work. By changing the ModelBinderAttribute to not include a specific type, it seems like Autofac picks the correct model binder, but it still doesn't resolve the dependency in the model binder. I'm getting the "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."-error.

Comment: If you still get the "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." then Autofac definitely not picks up your model binder otherwise you would get a different error...

Comment: It seems the `RegisterWebApiModelBinders` method is not working corroctly. And you need to explicitly register your modelbinders even if you don't specify the types in the attribute. But in this case you need write: `builder.RegisterType<RequestContextModelBinder>().AsModelBinderForTypes(typeof (RequestContext));`. Please try this out and if it is working then I'll update my answer with this info.

Comment: That did it nemesv. Thank you very much. So are you saying that there's a bug in the RegisterWebApiModelBinders extension method?

Comment: I don't know whether it is a bug or not. The `RegisterWebApiModelBinders` still registers your binders but not with the required metadata for the `AutofacWebApiModelBinderProvider`. Because this feature is completly undocumented in Autofac I don't know in which use cases are meant for the `RegisterWebApiModelBinders` method...

Comment: In this case, RegisterWebApiModelBinders doesn't seem to have any effect then? I don't see any reason for it when explicitly registering the model binder manually through RegisterType.

Comment: Probably it makes no sense to call `RegisterWebApiModelBinders` anymore... Because it registers the binders with the `IModelBinder` interface, but Web API does not use this for the resolving. Maybe this has been changed between Web API 1.0 and Web 2.0 API which eventually made this method useless. However you open an issue for this in the Autofac issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/

Comment: Will do. Thanks again for your help nemesv. https://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=484&thanks=484&ts=1390140942